# Golang - Missing expression error on structs

Tags: go, goland

```
type Old struct {
    UserID int `json:"user_ID"`
    Data   struct {
        Address string `json:"address"`
    } `json:"old_data"`
}

type New struct {
    UserID int `json:"userId"`
    Data   struct {
        Address string `json:"address"`
    } `json:"new_data"`
}

func (old Old) ToNew() New {
    return New{
        UserID: old.UserID,
        Data: { // from here it says missing expression
            Address: old.Data.Address,
        },
    }
}
```

What is **"missing expression"** error when using structs?
I am transforming old object to a new one. I minified them just to get straight to the point but the transformation is much more complex. The **UserID** field for example works great. But when I use struct (which intended to be a JSON object in the end) the Goland IDE screams **"missing expression"** and the compiler says "missing type in composite literal" on this line. What I am doing wrong? Maybe should I use something else instead of struct? Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Data` is an [anonymous struct](https://kelcecil.com/golang/2015/01/08/anonymous-structs-in-go.html), so you need to write it like this:

```
type New struct {
    UserID int `json:"userId"`
    Data   struct {
        Address string `json:"address"`
    } `json:"new_data"`
}

func (old Old) ToNew() New {
    return New{
        UserID: old.UserID,
        Data: struct {
            Address string `json:"address"`
        }{
            Address: old.Data.Address,
        },
    }
}
```

<sup>[(playground link)](https://play.golang.org/p/o7PFOI0eiCX)</sup>

I think it'd be cleanest to create a named `Address` struct.

Comment: thanks, it works. could you please explain why is it? why it does not take the "`json:"address"`" from the struct definition?

Comment: I assume it's because, as far as Go is concerned, a struct tagged fields and one without tagged fields are entirely disparate types.

Answer (score 4):

You're defining `Data` as an inline struct. When assigning values to it, you must first put the inline declaration:

```
func (old Old) ToNew() New {
    return New{
        UserID: old.UserID,
        Data: struct {
        Address string `json:"address"`
    }{
            Address: old.Data.Address,
        },
    }
}
```

Hence it is generally better to define a separate type for `Data`, just like `User`.